# How to notify a user after background task is finished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, sidekiq

I use rails with `ActiveJob` and `sidekiq` as backend. When user come on a page `sidekiq` create a long-term background task, how can I notice a user (by render partial on the web page) when a task would be completed?

Rails and sidekiq work as different processes. This fact confused me I don't understand how to handle completed status using background job.

Answer (score 6):

`ActiveJob` provides an [after_perform](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_perform) callback which according to docs work like this:

```
class VideoProcessJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  after_perform do |job|
    UserMailer.notify_video_processed(job.arguments.first)
  end

  def perform(video_id)
    Video.find(video_id).process
  end
end
```

So, you don't have to worry to integrate directly with `Sidekiq` or any other queuing backend, talk to `ActiveJob` :)

Comment: Thx, but I want to notice user by render partial on the web-page

Comment: @mystdeim the issue here is which web page! the user could have gone to anyone right? any render/redirect which could be possible won't be a good idea. Instead use some notification modal triggered by `ActionCable` subscription. Will try to post some code but it shouldn't be hard. Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

My approach in this situation is:

1. Add [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) so that background jobs can be tracked by ID.
2. In the client call that creates the background job, return the newly-created job's ID.

   ```
   class MyController < ApplicationController

     def create
       # sidekiq-status lets us retrieve a unique job ID when
       # creating a job
       job_id = Workers::MyJob.perform_async(...)

       # tell the client where to find the progress of this job
       return :json => {
         :next => "/my/progress?job_id={job_id}"
       }
     end

   end
   ```
3. Poll a 'progress' endpoint on the server with that job ID. This endpoint fetches job progress information for the job and returns it to the client.

   ```
   class MyController < ApplicationController

     def progress
       # fetch job status from sidekiq-status
       status = Sidekiq::Status::get_all(params[:job_id])

       # in practice, status can be nil if the info has expired from
       # Redis; I'm ignoring that for the purpose of this example

       if status["complete"]
         # job is complete; notify the client in some way
         # perhaps by sending it a rendered partial
         payload = {
           :html => render_to_string({
             :partial => "my/job_finished",
             :layout => nil
           })
         }
       else
         # tell client to check back again later
         payload = {:next => "/my/progress?job_id={params[:job_id]}"}
       end

       render :json => payload
     end

   end
   ```
4. If the client sees that the job has completed, it can then display a message or take whatever next step is required.

   ```
   var getProgress = function(progress_url, poll_interval) {
     $.get(progress_url).done(function(progress) {
       if(progress.html) {
         // job is complete; show HTML returned by server
         $('#my-container').html(progress.html);
       } else {
         // job is not yet complete, try again later at the URL
         // provided by the server
         setTimeout(function() {
           getProgress(progress.next, poll_interval);
         }, poll_interval);
       }
     });
   };
   $("#my-button").on('click', function(e) {
     $.post("/my").done(function(data) {
       getProgress(data.next, 5000);
     });
     e.preventDefault();
   });
   ```

Caveat emptor: that code is meant to be illustrative, and is missing things you should take care of such as error handling, preventing duplicate submissions, and so forth.

Comment: You do this in obsolete way with pooling and prefer push-notify with websocket or SSE

Comment: @mystdeim can you share an example of doing this more elegantly with websockets/SSE ? (I'm trying to figure out the best way to achieve this, but can't find many examples online unfortunately)